# Difference between symmetric and asymmetric matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph, symmetric, asymmetric

I'm practising with graphs and adjacency matrices. But I couldn't find a good example that differentiates symmetric and asymmetric matrix. Can anyone tell me how to distinguish the difference between symmetric or asymmetric matrix.

Comment: A web search for "symmetric matrix" turns up the answer.

Comment: it is actually programming, I'm working on a graph algorithm that requires working with adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 2):

An adjacency matrix is symmetric if it is derived from an undirected graph.

That means, the path from node A -> B has the same cost/weight/length as the path from node `B -> A`.

If you create the adjacency matrix `M`, it will be symmetric, meaning that for any `i` and `j`, `M[i][j] == M[j]i]`. More mathematically, the matrix is identical to its transpose. So if you transpose your matrix, it will look exactly the same. Graphically, such a matrix looks like this:

```
0 2 3 4
2 0 5 6
3 5 0 7
4 6 7 0
```

Due to the symmetry, you can often represent it using less memory. For algorithms like the [Floyd-Warshall-algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) on undirected graphs, you can reduce the amount of computation by 50% since you only need to compute half of the matrix:

```
0 2 3 4
  0 5 6
    0 7
      0
```

For comparison, an asymmetric matrix:

```
0 2 3 9 <--
2 0 5 6
3 5 0 7
4 6 7 0
```

Note, that it is almost identical to the previous example, but in the upper right corner, there is a `9`. So it is no longer possible to mirror the matrix along it's diagonal axis.

Comment: I also read that, if number columns equals to the rows that's a symmetric matrix. Is that also valid for the adjacency matrix.

Comment: If (number of columns == number of rows), then it is a **square** matrix. A *symmetric* matrix is a special case of a square matrix where the matrix is equal to the transposed matrix (see my answer)

Comment: @JVTura if your question is answered, please consider marking the answer. If not, please modify your question to give us more information about what you want to know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the example of symmetric graph

[image]

Comment: Would be a good idea to explain the concept a little further. How does the cells correspond each other?